# Angularjs dynamic name of ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I'am using AngularJS and I use an `ng-repeat` block. I want to use a unique/dynamic `ng-model` name. The idea of this code is that when I click the buttom I increase the value of the textbox. The name of the parameters is correct in the debugger but the value is not changing. Below there is the code that I use but it is not working and I can not find why. Can anyone help me please?

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in resultShoppingCart track by $index">
   <td class="price" ng-bind="item.unitPrice"><span></span></td>
   <td class="qty">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-value="item.quantity" ng-model="Qty['{{$index}}']">
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="addQuantity(item.quantity, item.productId, $index)"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
   </td>
   <td class="price" ng-bind="item.price"><span>$99.00</span></td>
   <td class="action"><a ng-click="delete(userId,item.productId)">Delete item</a></td>
</tr>
```

And my controller.

```
$scope.addQuantity = function (currentQuantity, productId, i) {          
          $scope["Qty['" + i + "']"] = currentQuantity + 1;
          alert($scope["Qty['" + i + "']"]);          
      }
```

Comment: can't you have `Qty[$index]` instead with `$scope.Qty[i]` in the controller?

Comment: I tried this and it is not working. it is the only way that I found in order to have o dynalic ng-model like this .Qty['1']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result of `'{{$index}}'` expression will be `'{{$index}}'` itself. So you have to change the expression to `Qty[$index]` rather than using `Qty['{{$index}}']` inside `ng-model`, so that interpolation will evaluate it correctly.

---

But I would recommend to use `item.quantity`, which ultimately going to be unique itself. No need to maintain separate object (as such I don't see any reason save Quantity in separately).

```
<td class="qty">                            
    <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-value="item.quantity" ng-model="item.quantity" >
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus" ng-click="addQuantity(item)"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>                            
</td>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.addQuantity = function (item) {          
    item.quantity = item.quantity + 1;
}
```

Comment: @Celia Glad to know it helped, Thanks ;)